# How can I color a curve envelope

Tags: r, graphics, plot

I am trying to color the envelope of a curve.
Say for example:

```
set.seed(1)
middle = seq(1,10,length.out=100)
upper = middle+5*runif(100)
lower = middle-5*runif(100)
plot(seq(100),middle,ylim=range(lower,middle,upper),type='l',col='red')
lines(upper,col='grey')
lines(lower,col='grey')
```

[image: plot]

How can I color in grey between the grey lines ?

Comment: use `polygon`, something like `polygon(c(xvals,rev(xvals)), c(min_y,max_y))` ... I feel like there must be a duplicate somewhere but can't find it quickly.

Comment: Yes, it is described in `demo(graphics)`.

Comment: @RHertel, good point (you could copy that information here as an answer if you like), but I meant specifically a StackOverflow duplicate ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possibility, as described in `demo(graphics)`

```
middle <- seq(1,10,length.out=100)
upper <- middle+5*runif(100)
lower <- middle-5*runif(100)
xx <- c(1:100,100:1)
yy <- c(upper,rev(lower))
plot(seq(100),middle,ylim=range(lower,middle,upper),type='l')
polygon(xx, yy, col="gray")
lines(seq(100),middle,ylim=range(lower,middle,upper),type='l',col='red')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
# ... Your code before plot( ... )
sequence = seq(100)
plot(sequence,middle,ylim=range(lower,middle,upper),type='l',col='red')
# After all the other code:
polygon(c(sequence, rev(sequence)), c(upper, rev(lower)), col = rgb( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 ), border = NA )
```

[image: Obligatory picture of output]